# Win32/MFC: How to find free memory (RAM) available?

Tags: windows, memory, mfc, winapi

Any suggestions/hints/links/tutorials would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to refine the question (or ask a new one) and to give more background information what you are trying to achieve, for what purpose you need to know the "free RAM" and what kind of memory operations your program does. Finding out and interpreting the state of memory correctly is not easy. Even if you know it you can never be sure that malloc/new operations succeed, due to memory fragmentation. I had the most terrible time in my carreer as a programmer because I believed: If I have enough RAM in my computer I won't have problems with memory operations. I was soooooo wrong.

Answer (score 9):

There really is no answer to this. Under normal circumstances, the OS will keep *something* in essentially all the memory on the system. Basically, once it's read something into memory, it'll keep a copy of it in memory until something else needs memory so the first one gets kicked out. There are a number of functions that can get you information about memory, but none of them even attempts to really return an amount of memory that's completely unused. The closest of which I'm aware is [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28VS.85%29.aspx), which does return a number for the amount of memory that's available.

That means whatever is currently in that memory is currently both in memory *and* on disk, so the copy in memory can be thrown away without having to write it to disk first. For example, if you ran a program, most of is code will stay in memory (until something else wants memory), in case you decide to run it again. Since it's just a copy of the program on disk, it can be thrown away, and (if necessary) reloaded from disk when needed.

If you want more detail, you can use things like [`VirtualQueryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366907%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get it -- but it'll usually overload you with information, telling you about each block of memory used in a given process, instead of giving a nice, simple number saying "x bytes free".

Answer (score 5):

GlobalMemoryStatus/GlobalMemoryStatusEx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366586(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty easy to answer, free RAM is always sufficiently close to 0 to consider it zero and not bother.  Unused RAM is always used by the file system cache, you can see this in the Taskmgr.exe, Performance tab.

If you actually mean "free virtual memory", the number you'd only really care about, then the answer is "not really possible".  You'd need HeapWalk(), a very awkward and dangerous function to use.  Only HeapWalk can detect blocks in the heap that are marked free but are still mapped.  The number you'd arrive at is meaningless anyway.  A program never runs out of free virtual memory blocks, it always runs out of large-enough memory blocks first.

Detecting this condition is easy enough.  Malloc returns NULL, the new operator throws std::bad_alloc.  Dealing with the condition is not easy.  Solving it takes less than two hundred bucks, roughly the license fee for a 64-bit version of Windows.