# How to determine amount of free RAM in C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

1. I want to determine the amount of free RAM at a particular instant so that I let the user know whether a particular operation is possible or not, depending upon whether necessary amount of RAM is available or not.

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513505/how-to-get-available-memory-c-g). But as Travis says, it is some what mix of paging & RAM. I would like to know only the free RAM memory.

2. Secondly I would like to understand how to use paging in Windows if necessary amount of RAM is not available.
   Thank You.

Comment: Google for 'Windows virtual memory management'

Comment: There is not a portable way of doing this.  You can use OS-specific APIs to get an idea of what's happening in a system but in general this is all purposefully transparent to applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get available memory C++/g++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513505/how-to-get-available-memory-c-g)

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for your advice! I found a beautiful article here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_memory_and_heaps.html

Comment: @NicolBolas what about the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I don't know enough about the subject to point you in the right direction, but the edit shows your effort and people have since answered your question.

Comment: For ms windows you should also look into address space, the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker setting and address space fragmentation if you are developing a 32 bit application. Remember that by default the address space of a 32 bit application is limited to 2GB regardless of the amount of ram you have in your PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About paging: paging is performed automatically if enabled in Windows. No need to change your code to use it.

About free memory: [Win32/MFC: How to find free memory (RAM) available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522943/win32-mfc-how-to-find-free-memory-ram-available)

You could also try to claim the memory. If successful, the operation can be performed. If you are going to use it anyway... This is not the nicest solution.